# Boolean Algebra-Simplification Assistance Needed

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics, computer-science, boolean-algebra

I have to show that (!(P.Q) + R)(!Q + P.!R) => !Q by simplifying it using De Morgan's Laws. Here is what I did but I'm not sure it's right.

(!(P.Q) + R)(!Q + P.!R) => !Q

(!P + !Q + R)(!Q + P.!R)

!(P.Q) + !P.P.!R + !Q + !Q.P.!R + R.!Q + R.P.!R

!(P.Q) + 0 + !Q + !Q.P.!Q + R.!Q + 0

!(P.Q) + !Q + !Q(1 + P.!R + R)

!(P.Q) + !Q + !Q

!Q + !(P.Q)

!Q(1 + !P)

!Q

Hope that's clear enough.

Comment: The sedond line: how did $(P' · Q' + R)$ turn into $(P' + Q' + R)$?

Comment: De Morgan's Law !(P.Q) = !P + !Q, did I do it wrong?

Comment: But there is $P' · Q'$ and not $(P · Q)'$.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that I wasn't sure how to type it out. It's P.Q Negated with the line above it, so I think it should be !(P.Q) I'll have to edit the question if this is right,

Comment: Actually since $Q'$ is in both conjunts of the second line expression, you can factor it out immediately: $(P' + Q' + R)(Q' + PR') = Q' + (P' + R)(PR')$ which implies $Q'$

Comment: Does the reset of the expression cancel itself out? If so then thanks!! Oh, and is the way I did it still right?

Comment: No the rest of the expression does not cancel itself out and that's not what you want to prove. It's just $Q' + x \implies Q'$ but $Q' + x \iff Q'$ doesn't hold. Your way is still right modulo the point I just made.

Comment: So the question isn't to simplify the left side until it's !Q? If so, then I'm guessing I should have included the right side ( => !Q) and simplify the whole expression? If so, how do I know when to stop symplifying? I'm sorry about all these questions but I always had a problem with symplifying expressions.

Comment: Aww man sorry about it but I made a mistake when typing out the question its (!(P.Q) + R)(!Q + P.!R) <=> !Q, so it's asking me to simplify the left side to prove that it's equal to !Q?

Comment: Your question is to prove that $((PQ)' + R)(Q' + PR) \implies Q'$ is a propositional tautology which is the same as simplifying $((PQ)' + R)(Q' + PR) ≤ Q'$ to $1$.

Comment: Ok, in that case $(P' + R)(PR')$ actualy cancels itself out however it wouldn't be needed for the alteranative question. You should definitely write the question accordingly to what do you want to ask…

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, your work is correct. Let's shorten things up, though, using the Distributive Law  (D.L.) twice immediately following the application of DeMorgan's:

$\begin{align}(\overline{P\cdot Q} + R)\cdot (\overline Q + P\cdot \overline R) &= (\overline P + \overline Q + R)\cdot(\overline Q + P\cdot \overline R) \tag{DeMorgan's} \\ \\ & =  \overline Q + (\overline P + R)(P\cdot \overline R) \tag{D.L.} \\ \\ & = \overline Q + (\color{blue}{\overline P\cdot P}\cdot \overline R) + (\color{red}{R}\cdot P\cdot \color{red}{ \overline R}) \tag{D.L.}\\ \\ & = \overline Q + \color{blue}{ 0} + \color{red}{\bf 0} \tag{$A \cdot \overline A = 0$}\\ \\ &= Q'\end{align}$

Comment: $\Large{+}^\infty $

Comment: @amWhy: very instructive +1

Answer (score 0):

Yes your simplification is right, but can be done shorter way:
$((PQ)' + R)(Q' + PR') = (P' + Q' + R)(Q' + PR') = Q' + (P' + R)(PR') = Q' + P'PR' + RPR' = Q' + 0 + 0 = Q'$.